# to fix URL content based SQL injection

Tags: sql, jdbc, sql-injection

I was trying to fix SQL injection for my Application. SQL query I am using to get the details is

```
"SELECT accountNumber, balance FROM accounts WHERE reg_id = " 
  + request.getParameter("reg_id");
```

I know this query is vulnerable and that's why I was trying to use bind parameters to fix this but the issue is reg_id is Alphanumeric data along with "-" (hyphen as special symbol e.g.- 1abh34-dfg465-aw234)and I can't use `statement.setInt()` and `statement.setString()` method to validate reg_id.

My Question is, is there any method I can use to validate Alphanumeric data?

My java code is

```
String accountBalanceQuery = 
  "SELECT accountNumber, balance FROM accounts WHERE reg_id = " 
  + request.getParameter("reg_id");

try {
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(accountBalanceQuery);
    while (rs.next()) {
        page.addTableRow(rs.getInt("accountNumber"), rs.getFloat("balance"));
    }
} catch (SQLException e) { ... }
```

Or is there any  other way I can fix this vulnerability without bind parameters. Any lead on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the data type of `reg_id` in the database? I don't see any reason you can't use a PreparedStatement here. If it's "alphanumeric", then `setString()` seems like a perfect fit (especially because `getParameter()` returns a String as well)

Comment: it's a varchar.

Comment: Then you can use `setString()` - what exactly is the reason that you think you can't use that?

Comment: My application Scanning tool adding && !sleep(11000) && "1 after SQL statement. So I am not sure that will Vaildate the reg_id parameter for only required input.

Comment: What do you mean with "validate". Obviously if such a value is passed, the select statement won't return anything because the comparison fails. Using a `PreparedStatement` is the only and best choice you have here and there is absolutely no reason not to use it

Comment: Sure , let me try this and will let you know

Comment: There is no way a query parameter can let a malicious SQL injection attack through. Query parameters are not just another way to concatenate strings, they keep the parameter separate from the SQL query until _after_ it has been parsed by the database server. Once the SQL has been parsed, no malicious content can change the syntax of the query. So the attempted malicious content will only result in a query that doesn't match any rows, not a query that does extra logic.

Comment: Appreciate your response Bill , But I am confuse here. How can SQL query be parsed without having details what's exactly it needs to search in database. for e.g. here how can we get the details from account without mentioning particular reg_id. I can see my Application scan tools is adding services/balance?reg_id=2zc8-44n5-r8a0" && !sleep(11000) && "1 and it's effecting database.